# SQL Server Connection Problems

Tags: sql-server, connection, pymssql

I just upgraded to a Windows 7 box and installed MS SQL Server 2005 and am trying to open and connect to my local machine using Windows Authentication.

I keep getting 'Cannot connect to CHRISW7O980'.  Do I have to start a server locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest using this [fantastic ServerFault answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/191576/sql-server-cant-connect/191587#191587) to a similar question to help troubleshoot connectivity issues to new instances of SQL Server. There are a few configuration points to check.

Some likely culprits:

- W7 firewall allowing SQL Server traffic on 1433.
- SQL Server services running?
- SQL Server Configuration Manager not allowing TCP connections.

[SQL Server Can't Connect](https://serverfault.com/questions/191576/sql-server-cant-connect/191587#191587)

Comment: The SQL Server Configuration Manager says that SQL Server is Running and is set to Automatic.  I'll check the firewall now

Comment: nope its not the firewall, turned it off and still nothing.  It appears that SQL SERVER (MSSQLSERVER) service is started and automatic

Answer (score 1):

Check in Sql Server Configuration Manager to ensure your instance of SQL Server is running.  If not, you can start it and set the Start Mode to Automatic to automatically start it when windows reboots.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are running SQLExpress? Try this for the instance name:

Try using `.\SQLEXPRESS`.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed SQL Server on your local machine, did you install SQL EXPRESS? If so, you may have to use the instance name CHRISW7O980\SQLEXPRESS.

Also, remember that connections over TCP/IP are disabled for newly installed SQL servers. You'll have to enable that in the SQL server manager.